# Why does my code ignore my if statement for my hangman game? (python)

Tags: python, syntax

I just had a question about the code that I wrote below. I was just wondering about the if statement that I wrote with the "if guess not in secret_word:". When I run it as it's currently written, the condition doesn't even run or appear. However, when I swap it with the for statement which I wrote above, it runs just fine. I'm a bit new to programming, and I was just wondering if anyone could help me out with this. Why does the order of conditions matter here?

'''

```
import random
from words import words

secret_word = random.choice(words)
secret_letters = list(secret_word)
blanks = " _ " * len(secret_word)
already_guessed = []
lives = 10

print(blanks)


def valid_guess(): # function to make sure the letter guessed is valid (ie, not previously guessed)
    is_letter = True
    lives = 10

    while True:
        guess = (input("\nGuess a letter:"))

        if guess in already_guessed:
            print("You have already guessed this letter")
        elif len(guess) != 1:
            print("Please guess a single letter:")
            is_letter = False
        elif guess not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("Please guess a LETTER:")
            is_letter = False

        if is_letter:
            already_guessed.append(guess)

        for guess in secret_word:
            if guess in already_guessed:
                print(guess + " ", end = "")
            else:
                print(" - ", end = "")

        if guess not in secret_word:
            lives -= 1
            print(f"You lost a life! You only have {lives}/10 left!")


while True:
    valid_guess()
```

'''

Comment: The `guess` you get from user input has been overwritten by `for guess in secret_word`.  Perhaps you wanted `if guess in secret_word`, instead of `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if guess in secret_word:
       if guess in already_guessed:
            print(guess + " ", end = "")
       else:
            print(" - ", end = "")

 elif guess not in secret_word:
       lives -= 1
       print(f"You lost a life! You only have {lives}/10 left!")
```